# Catching applet exceptions in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, exception, applet

In IE in the ff. code, the catch clause is entered if someMethodThatThrowsExceptions does throw an exception.  However, this is not the case in Firefox.  Is this a limitation in Firefox's Javascript engine or LiveConnect implementation?  Does a workaround exist?

```
try {
  document.applets["someApplet"].someMethodThatThrowsExceptions();
} catch (e) {
  handleError();
}
```

Comment: Without seeing more representative code of what you are actually doing, it's really impossible to say.  Try to make a reduced testcase?

Comment: Improved description of problem.  I might have led people to believe that my problem is with handleError's invocation.  This is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked where I should have checked in the first place: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/LiveConnect.  Found out that this is a known problem in a certain LiveConnect version.  Discussion, solution and work-around here: http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=45933&tstart=0.

Comment: Second link isn't available anymore... could you edit your question to display the work-around?? I'm having a similar problem with Chrome where I can't get the Java Exception error message after getting into the catch clause. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, man.  I can't remember what I did myself.  I tried to look for a way to map the new link to the new one but all I found was this: http://java.net/jira/browse/ABOUT-153.

Answer (score -2):

use

```
document.getElementById('someApplet').someMethodThatThrowsException()
```

Comment: The problem is not with the reference to someApplet.  Rather, it is with the catching of the exceptions being thrown by someMethodThatThrowsExceptions.

Comment: are you sure, someMethodThatThrowsException() executes in FF? Than ok, my answer is wrong. But anyway, why are you using applets.['applet_name'] instead getElementById?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the method executes in FF because I see the stack trace in the console.

I'm using the applets property because it makes it seem clearer that the object you are referencing is an applet and not an HTML element customized with extra functions.